# django.core.urlresolver.reverse - NoReverseMatch: Reverse for '...' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, django-cms

I have a problem with url resolution in a view:

```
# URLS.PY
from django.conf.urls.defaults import url, include, patterns
from acomea.contact.cms.views import (
    ConfirmPrivacyFormView, CancelContactTemplateView, ConfirmPrivacyDataTemplateView, CancelMailSentTemplateView
)
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(
       r'^',
       ConfirmPrivacyFormView.as_view(),
       name="contact_contact_confirm_privacy_form"
    ),
    url(
       r'^/data-confirmed/$',
       ConfirmPrivacyDataTemplateView.as_view(),
       name="contact_contact_confirm_privacy_accept_data"
    ),
    url(
       r'^/mailsent/',
       CancelMailSentTemplateView.as_view(),
       name="contact_contact_confirm_privacy_delete_mailsent"
    ),
    url(
       r'^/remove-contact/',
       CancelContactTemplateView.as_view(),
       name="contact_contact_confirm_privacy_delete_contact"
    ),
)


# resolve

>>>from django.core.urlresolver import reverse
>>>reverse("contact_contact_confirm_privacy_accept_data")
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'contact_contact_confirm_privacy_accept_data' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

I experienced this problem other times, also in the admin with urls defined in `get_urls()` method. I've tried to search on the internet any suitable solution but none of them did't worked for me.
Any help?

Thanks
L.

Comment: Try to remove the head slash?

Answer (score 1):

Try: 
1. add $ to url like `r'^/mailsent/$'` 
2. use from `django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url` instead 
 Otherwise:
D:\Program Files (x86)\python273\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls\defaults.py:3: DeprecationWarning: django.conf.urls.defaults is deprecated; use django.conf.urls instead
  DeprecationWarning) 
3. `from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse` notice the 's' at the end of urlresolvers 
4. You can use [reverse_lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy) instead